# Changing words to Cohen's "Hallelujah"

Tags: lyrics

I have heard at least four different sets of lyrics to Cohen's Hallelujah.  But in spite of having very different overall themes, none of them changed the lines "the fourth, the fifth / the minor fall, the major lift."

Why is that line seemingly too important to change?  I realize that it describes its own chord progression, but that fact is generally irrelevant to the theme of each adaptation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would better suit Music Fans SE site. https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/